# Python wildcard folder with glob

Tags: python, directory, wildcard, glob

My ant script creates a folder with date and time enf of the folder in D:\test\ folder.

How to copy d:\test\apps_20150709_updates_**2015_08_03_13-54**\apps\dist\packages\ folder to D:\test\packages. Date and time always changing (**2015_08_03_13-54**). I tried use glob command in this script can you help me?

```
import os, shutil, glob

SOURCE = glob.glob("D:\\test\\apps_20150709_updates_*\\apps\\dist\\packages\\")

DEST = "D:\\test\\packages\\"

shutil.copytree(SOURCE, DEST)

print os.listdir(DEST)
```

---

```
***D:\test>python copy_files.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "copy_files.py", line 6, in <module>
    shutil.copytree(SOURCE, DEST)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 171, in copytree
    names = os.listdir(src)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found
D:\test>***
```

Comment: Could there ever be more than one folder matching the `D:\test\apps_20150709_updates_*` part?

Comment: Date and time always automatically creating d:\test\apps_20150709_updates_2015_08_03_13-54\apps\dist\packages\ d:\test\apps_20150709_updates_2015_08_03_14-20\apps\dist\packages\ there are lots of same folders. I want to only copy packages folder and subfolders to d:\test\packages.

Comment: My question was could there also be, for example, a `d:\test\apps_20150709_updates_2015_08_04_13-54\apps\dist\packages` folder?

Comment: Yes packages is a folder and there are subfolders and another jar and war files.

Comment: OK, so if there's more than `d:\test\apps_20150709_updates_<some_date>\apps\dist\packages`, do you want to copy them all?

Comment: Yes i want to copy all subfolders and files to d:\test\packages folder

Comment: Yes i want to copy all subfolders and files to d:\test\packages folder there are war and jar files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other answer points out, you're passing a list to `shutil.copytree()` which expects each argument to be a string. To fix that, try the following which will copy all matching source folders to the destination folder:

```
import os, shutil, glob

SOURCE = glob.glob("D:\\test\\apps_20150709_updates_*\\apps\\dist\\packages\\")
DEST = "D:\\test\\packages\\"

for folder in SOURCE:
    shutil.copytree(folder, DEST)

print os.listdir(DEST)
```

Comment: You're welcome. Note, too, that in Python you can use `r"D:\test\apps_20150709_updates_*\apps\dist\packages"` for strings with backslashes in them (you don't need the trailing ones).

Answer (score 0):

`glob.glob` returns a **list** of matching paths **or an empty list** in case no match was found.

`shutil.copytree` **expects a string** in the first parameter ("need string or buffer") **and you provided the list** instead ("list found").

Comment: Can you explain? im new in python.

Comment: @intelceptor: You're passing an argument of the wrong type to `shutil.copytree()`.